# Xor of numbers in a range

Tags: data-structures, xor, xor-linkedlist

I just came across a question which goes like this

Given an array of n elements , there are m queries of type l,r,t where in the program must take out xor of all numbers less than t and  between index l,r (both inclusive and 0-indexed) .

Example :
Say 
arr={2,3,5,1}
Our query is : 0 2 4
Output 1

I can only think of the naive solution of going through the range and just taking the xor of all the numbers less than t but I was just wondering is there any data structure like segment trees which could achieve the task in an efficient manner ?

Comment: Yes. I think Segment tree can work here. You can refer to this link for more info on similar kind of problem. It does XOR of elements in range l,r. I think your problem is an extension of the same problem.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-3-xor-given-range/

Comment: Don't know if you notice but I need xor of all elements less than t

Comment: Yes. I think we can apply that `t` constraint here in the link I mentioned. I am not sure as I am still trying to do it with that `t` constraint you mentioned. Will let you know if it is actually feasible.

Comment: This problem was at SO some times in last days. Definitely online contest or homework.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

1. Save all the numbers with its index and sort them according to their values (let's call it an array a).
2. First save all the queries with query id and sort them according to t (let's call it an array q).
3. Take a segment tree where every node contains 0 by default. It is a segment tree that contains xor in range.
4. Iterate over q and add all the numbers from a in the segment tree those are less than t for each query and take the xor in the given query range of that and save it to an array using query id (let's all it ans).
5. Print the ans array.

Complexity of this solution is O(n*log(n) + m*log(n)).